# What is the PROPER way to create an ASPX View in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Essentially, my issue is this: I'm trying to display a ViewData variable on an ASPX page, but I'm getting "ViewData does not exist in the current context."

What led me here? I'm new to MVC, and am following an online tutorial.  In Lesson 1, he has us create a view by going to Add > View, which creates a Razor view.  Then, in the next tutorial, he's teaching us to use ViewData to pass a variable to the view.  But, when he displays it, he's doing so using the <%: %> method, which doesn't work on my Razor page.  So, I try to create an ASPX page in my View folder by creating a Web Form the traditional way.  When I do that, I get the error mentioned above.  I have successfully figured out how to get the Razor method working in my cshtml page, but what is the appropriate method should I want to do it the "angle bracket - percent" way?

Edit: Basically, all I did was follow the instructions for Tutorial 2 in the following walk-through.  He doesn't really explain HOW he created the ASPX page (or that he used an ASPX page at all).  If anyone knows of a better tutorial that's more complete, I'm all ears.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in#Lab1:- Creating a simple hello world ASP.NET MVC Application

Edit2: By request, here's my code:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="MVCLearn.Views.FirstMVC.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%= ViewData["vwTest"] %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Controller:

```
    public class FirstMVCController : Controller
    {
        // GET: FirstMVC
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["vwtest"] = "Something";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SayHello()
        {
            return View("HelloView");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use ASPX views?

Comment: Don't use ViewData use ViewModels, also you don't need <%: %> use @ http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29

Comment: Could you share your cshtml and aspx code?

Comment: Because I want to follow along with the tutorial, and I want to know how to get the ASPX method to work.  Mine is an inquisitive quest for understanding lol

Comment: It's good to know, don't worry. I also am nosy about this issue, so post the code, please.

Comment: This tutorial was created two weeks ago? Avoid it. It's full of errors. It also seems to be copy-pasted together from various sources. Just go to http://www.asp.net/mvc/.

Comment: Agreed, this tutorial is pretty terrible. I have no idea why one would want to mix aspx and razor syntaxes. And using ViewData instead of ViewModels is just one of the many bad practices in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <%= ViewData["vwTest"] %>
  ViewData["vwtest"] = "Something";
```

vwTest != vwtest

You should write same name

```
   <%= ViewData["vwTest"] %>
      ViewData["vwTest"] = "Something";
```

Comment: Been a while since I looked, but I'm 99.32% sure that `ViewData` is a case-insensitive dictionary.